# Implicit function theorem for $f:\mathbb{R}^{3} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am stuck at this problem and I would be glad if somebody helped me out:

By the implicit function theorem, it should be shown that: $$f(x,y,z) := z^{3}+2xy-4xz+2y-1 .$$

The zero level set $f^{-1}(0)$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0, y_0) = (1,1)$ can be rewritten through a differentiable function $z=g(x,y)$ where $g(1,1)=1$. Then also the partial derivatives: $g_x(1,1), g_y(1,1)$ should be calculated.

The partial derivative in respect to $z$ is: $f_z = 3z^2- 4x$ and it holds that $3z^2 - 4x \ne 0$, because otherwise the invertibility would not be given anymore. So if $(x_0, y_0)=(1,1)$ then $z^3- 4z+4=0$ gives $3$ solutions, of which none are such that $3z^2-4 = 0$. So the zero level set in $U$ can be rewritten through $g(x,y)$.

Now the remaining task is to solve $z^3 +2xy-4xz+2y-1=0$ for $z$. I sit around at this end:

$$z^3- 4xz=-2xy-2y+1 = z(z^2- 4x)=-2xy-2y+1 \Rightarrow z = \frac{-2xy-2y+1}{z^2-4x} .$$

According to Wolfram Alpha, there are [3 exact solutions](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%20z%5E%283%29%2b2x%2ay-4%2ax%2az%2b2%2ay-1%20for%20z).

Comment: I think you need to check that $f_z$ is non-zero at $(1,1,1)$. Isn't that point given?

Comment: $z^{3}+2xy-4xz+2y-1=0$ has three solutions for $z$ for fixed  $x$ and $y$ because it is a cubic equation.  For $x=y=1$ the solutions are $z=1$ and $\frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{13}}{2}$.  But you seem to be missing part of the question.

Comment: @Dylan Moreland Thanks!  $f_{z}$ is -1 at (1,1,1). But why (1,1,1)? I don't see where you want me to go with this, either...

Comment: @Tashi $g$ is spitting out $z$-values, and you're told that it's spitting out $1$ at $(1,1)$. Maybe I'm misinterpreting the question?

Comment: Thanks @Dylan Moreland: I understood what you mean with $f_{z}$ non zero at (1,1). So there is no need to find $g(x,y)$? How to calculate $g_{x}(1,1)$ and $g_{y}(1,1)$ without knowing $g(x,y)$ ?

Comment: @Tashi I think the idea is to use implicit differentiation and the chain rule for multivariable functions.

Answer (score 2):

By [implicit function theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem), if we can show that $f_z(1,1)\neq 0$, then "the zero level set $f^{−1}(0)$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0)=(1,1)$ can be rewritten through a differentiable function $z=g(x,y)$", as you would like to show. To see this, we have
$$f_z(1,1)=3z^{2}-4x\Big|_{(x,y,z)=(1,1,1)}=3-4=-1\neq 0.$$
Now, sinc $f^{−1}(0)$ can be written as $z=g(x,y)$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $(x_0,y_0)=(1,1)$, we have 
$f(x,y,g(x,y))=0$, or equivalently,
$$g(x,y)^{3}+2xy-4xg(x,y)+2y-1=0.$$
Now, take the partial derivative of the above equation with respect to $x$, we obtain
$$3g^2(x,y)g_x(x,y)+2y-4g(x,y)-4xg_x(x,y)=0.$$
Evaluate it at $(x,y)=1$ and by $g(1,1)=1$, we have
$$3g_x(1,1)+2-4-4g_x(1,1)=0,$$
which implies that $g_x(1,1)=-2$. Similarly, take the partial derivative of the above equation with respect to $y$, evaluate it at $(x,y)=1$, we obtain
$$3g^2(1,1)g_y(1,1)+2-4g_y(1,1)+2=0.$$
Since $g(1,1)=1$, we get $g_y(1,1)=4$